# Установка Python в пустой контейнер UBUNTU в Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, docker

Установил Docker CE на Ubuntu 20.04. Создал первый контейнер на основе пустого контейнера ubuntu. Это контейнер c голым linux16 без python, sudo nano и тд.

Пытаюсь установить в него Python:

```
# apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3
```

Пытаюсь установить wget для того, чтобы скачать пакет Python и установить Python из конкретного пакета.

```
# apt-get install wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wget
```

Делал:

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Много что перепробовал. Docker-compose установился. Подразумеваю, что надо что-то добавить в контейнер из основного linux20.04, где все стоит: и сам docker, и python3.8.5 и сам проект на django,который надо теперь засунуть в docker контейнер и чтобы ничего лишнего и конфиденциального не залетело в контейнер, кроме этого проекта. После установки python в контейнер планировал перенести туда только проект и запустить его и все. И передать контейнер заказчику. Может быть, можно с моего основного Linux20.04 выдернуть всю систему с Python? Главное, чтобы никакие другие проекты и конфиденциальные файлы не улетели в контейнер. Думал, что установить пустой Linux и Python и один проект только - самый безопасный и верный путь.

Подскажите, с чего начать, чтобы в пустом docker-контейнере в итоге установился сначала python хотя бы и потом проект на django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Апт не должен запускаться в докере, докер устроен подругому. Но если хочется починить:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
EOF

apt update
apt install
```

Но лучше пользуйтесь средствами докер для установки питона в докер. https://hub.docker.com/_/python **- Вам нужен** `python:3.8-buster`.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/ - следуйте этим инструкциям по созданию контейнера с django.

Comment: Я прочитал, что надо в моей ос linux20.04, где стоит проект, собрать dockerfile только с одним проектом и вот из этого файла уже сделать контейнер, чтобы проверить работу проекта в контейнере, и если все ок, то отдавать dockerfile заказчику. Если этот путь лучший, чем тот, по которому я пошел, то попробую сначала его. Хотя и первый путь нужен наверно, чтобы был подготовленный контейнер со всеми питонами и библиотеками для будущих проектов.

Comment: контейнеры докер выполняют только одну задачу - предоставить только один инструмент. не надо делать универсальный контейнер - в нем нет смысла так как он становится равнозначен установке на хост системе.